# Annotations created with iTextSharp not showing up

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a PDF of a blank 1-page MS Word doc.  I want to add a text box to it.  Code as follows:

```
void addAnnotation()
{
    string filename = @"C:\Users\userID\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\PDFConverterTester\TestAddSrc.pdf";
    string destFile = @"C:\Users\userID\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\PDFConverterTester\TestAddDest.pdf";
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(filename);
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(destFile, FileMode.Create);
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, stream);

    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(100,100, 100, 100);
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = pdfStamper.Writer;
    PdfAnnotation annot = PdfAnnotation.CreateStamp(pdfWriter, rect, "XYZABC add rect", "new rectangle");
    pdfStamper.AddAnnotation(annot, 1);
    pdfStamper.Close();
}
```

When I open `TestAddDest.pdf`, it's blank, just like the source PDF, and the file size is the same, so I'm assuming the annotation has not been added.  How can I add this text box?

Edit:

Source PDF: http://docdro.id/jAOpxr3

Destination PDF: http://docdro.id/gOaHsQm

Comment: When I run your code against a blank PDF I get the expected annotation in the new file. Can you post your before and after PDFs somewhere for us to inspect?

Comment: @ChrisHaas, done, see edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the PDF is blank is because the `Rectangle` is zero width and zero height :

> iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = new
>   iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(100,100, 100, 100);

Put a breakpoint on that line or:

```
Console.WriteLine("W: {0}, H: {1}", rect.Width, rect.Height);
```

output:

> W: 0, H: 0

Try something like this, which places the `Rectangle` at the top of the page:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(20, 700, 400, 776);
```

Destination PDF:

[image]